# the equivalent of scalac -print from within sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to run the equivalent of scalac -print on one or more classes interactively within sbt (0.11.2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-print` is a standard option to scalac, so you can add it to your `scalacOptions` like usual.  As an example, the following sbt session demonstrates temporarily adding it and recompiling:

```
$ sbt
> set scalacOptions in Compile += "-print"
> compile
...
```

However, this will recompile all sources (due to the options being different) and is not suitable for inspecting a small number of files out of a project of a decent size.  I expect the REPL's power mode has a better solution, but it depends on your underlying problem.